# What are the "built-in" filter options for ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid

I see a reference to a built-in filter for "empty" in the doc below.  Where can I find documentation for all built-in filter options?

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/#adding-custom-filter-options

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find it in the documentation either.
 However, you can look at the definition of the `BaseFilter` of the [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) here on the [GitHub](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/master/packages/ag-grid-community/src/ts/filter/baseFilter.ts#L56) and get all the built-in filters.

```js
export abstract class  BaseFilter<T, P extends IFilterParams, M> extends Component implements IFilterComp {

  public static EMPTY = 'empty';
  public static EQUALS = 'equals';
  public static NOT_EQUAL = 'notEqual';
  public static LESS_THAN = 'lessThan';
  public static LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL = 'lessThanOrEqual';
  public static GREATER_THAN = 'greaterThan';
  public static GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL = 'greaterThanOrEqual';
  public static IN_RANGE = 'inRange';

  public static CONTAINS = 'contains'; //1;
  public static NOT_CONTAINS = 'notContains'; //1;
  public static STARTS_WITH = 'startsWith'; //4;
  public static ENDS_WITH = 'endsWith'; //5;
  // .....
}
```

Comment: Here is a link to the official documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-provided-simple/#filterOptions